# replace more than 2 different words within a string

Tags: php, arrays, regex, replace

I have a string contains shortcodes that I would like to be replaced with array values let suppose if there are 2 different names within a string that I would like to replace with matched array values i.e `array('pizza', 'fruit');` is for replacing with `(Hello world lorem ipsum [name='apple'] lorem ipsum [name='bread'])`

so   `[name='apple']` to be replaced with fruit
and `[name='bread']` to be replaced with pizza

Within my current code it is replacing perfectly when the placing is in order of placed values but when i switch the words placing in array it replacing in the order of array sequence

```
$content = "Hello world this is a lorem ipsum text [shortcode name='generate'] this is used for some [shortcode id='2' name='corusel'] dummy words";
preg_match_all("/\[(.*?)\]/", $content, $matches);

$values = array();

foreach($matches[1] as $match) {
    if(is_array($match)) {
        foreach($match as $value) {
            echo $values = str_replace($match, "[$match]", $match);
            $value2 = explode(" ", $match);

            echo "<br />";
        }
    } else {
        $values[] = str_replace($match, "[$match]", $match);
        $value2 = explode(" ", $match);
        $value3 = explode("=", $value2[1]);
        if(isset($value2[2])) {$value4 = explode("=", $value2[2]);}
        $val1   = str_replace("'", "", $value3[1]);
        if(isset($value4[1])) {$val2   = str_replace("'", "", $value4[1]);}
        if(isset($val2)){$val2;}
        echo "<br />";
    }
}

$text = array('corusel', 'generate');
print_r($values);
echo "<br />";
echo str_replace($values, $text, $content);
```

**output :**

> Array ( [0] => [shortcode name='generate'] [1] => [shortcode id='2'
>   name='corusel'] )  Hello world this is a lorem ipsum text corusel this
>   is used for some generate dummy words

corusel is replacing generate this is wrong it should replace corusel and generate should be replaced by generate when i switch position it works perfectly

Comment: Is the value to be replaced found in `id` or in `name` ?

Comment: the value is being replaced by name

Comment: Then `[shortcode id='generate']` would do nothing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the substitute can be found in the attribute `name` (your question is not clear on the matter), your goal can be achieved pretty easily (no need to loop over the matches and explode, etc.):

```
<?php
$content = "Hello world this is a lorem ipsum text [shortcode name='generate'] this is used for some [shortcode id='2' name='corusel'] dummy words";
$regex = '~\[.*?name=([\'"])([^\'"]+)\1\]~';
# look for name=, followed by single or double quotes
# capture everything that is not a double/single quote into group2
# match the previously captured quotes
# the whole construct needs to be in square brackets

$content = preg_replace($regex, "$2", $content);
echo $content;
// output: Hello world this is a lorem ipsum text generate this is used for some corusel dummy words
?>
```

See an additional [demo on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/kL6uE1/1).

To only **get** the values (i.e. not replacing anything yet) of the `name` attribute, you can call `preg_match_all()` after the regex definition:

```
preg_match_all($regex, $content, $matches);
print_r($matches);
// your name values are in $matches[2]
```

You can even go **further** and replace the whole `shortcode` thingy with anything you want:

```
<?php
$content = "Hello world this is a lorem ipsum text [shortcode name='generate'] this is used for some [shortcode id='2' name='carousel'] dummy words";
$regex = '~\[.*?name=([\'"])([^\'"]+)\1\]~';

$replacements = array("generate" => "Some generator stuff here", "carousel" => "Rollercoaster");   

$content = preg_replace_callback($regex, 
    function ($match) {
        global $replacements;
        $key = $match[2];
        return $replacements[$key];
    },
    $content
    );
echo $content;

// output: Hello world this is a lorem ipsum text Some generator stuff here this is used for some Rollercoaster dummy words
?>
```

Comment: would be able to do name replace but I want whole shortcode to be replaced not only the name

Comment: the one you provided $2 did not understood ??

Comment: `$2` holds the captured values from the second group, in the above case everything between `name='` and `'`

Comment: okay so in my case its array('corusel', 'generate'); or more then 2 so in the place of $2 ?? can you please clear this

Comment: Got you got the concept now awesome and for both id and name ?? [shortcode name='generate' id='2']

Comment: @UsmanKhan: I do not really understand your second question, what do you need the id for (i.e. is there anything to replace)?

Comment: in order to replace the short code with the context i would like to get the name  used in the shortcode i'e what name is placed within the shortcode can I get that ?

Comment: the loop and other codes was made because I would like to replace the functions with the codes ie corusel will be replaced with slider and if I cant get the name wont be able to replace is'nt it ?

Comment: @UsmanKhan: Look into the answer again (at the bottom), I guess this is what you actually want.

Comment: you rocks awesome man you solved my problem genius :) Maybe I could be in future :)